# Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello
i'm new with ROS i'm trysing to build simple C++ file using catkin_make for my ROS indigo (OS UBUNTU 14.04 LTS) and i having errors that i can't figure out

having some og this errors :

```
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2096:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2096:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::detail::lexical_stream_limited_src<CharT, Traits, RequiresStringbuffer>::operator>>(int)’:
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:53: error: expected type-specifier
                 return ((*this) >> reinterpret_cast<boost::array<char, N>& >(output)); 
                                                     ^
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:53: error: expected ‘>’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:53: error: expected ‘(’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:53: error: ‘array’ is not a member of ‘boost’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:66: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
                 return ((*this) >> reinterpret_cast<boost::array<char, N>& >(output)); 
                                                                  ^
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2102:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
make[2]: *** [agitr/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/hello.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [agitr/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

---

Edit:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc,argv,"hello");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ROS_INFO_STREAM("hello");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206880/invoking-%22make--j2--l2%22-failed/) by [CEAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22107/ceas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2015-04-08**:
This looks like a C++ syntax error in hello.cpp . Can you post that file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-09**:
@CEAS: I've updated your question with the contents of your comment. Please update your question in the future, if any commenter asks for it.

**Comment by [CEAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22107/ceas/) on 2015-04-09**:
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's working now. It just needed to be correctly updated :D
After few delete, restore, delete, restore it started working by itself

thank you all ^^

---

Originally posted by [CEAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22107/ceas/) with karma: 31 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0